# How obscene is "stick it up your ass"?

Tags: offensive-language

The host of a US late night TV show often jokes about the list of words his broadcasting network prohibits him to use on air. FCC monitors broadcasts in terms of "obscenity, indecency, or profanity". He can not use the word "cock" but "stick it up your ass" was okay.

As an ESL speaker, can you help me understand how obscene  or offensive is "stick it up your ass" in the spectrum of potentially offensive language? For example how does it rate compared to medical, colloquial, or slang names for sexual organs. How about in comparison to different ways to describe sexual acts?

I understand that the answer could be subjective and the nature of this question relates to cultural differences among English speaking countries; I would appreciate if you could explain with more categories or levels of offensiveness than I came up with here or give examples from other English speaking cultures.

Comment: Phrases are not officially graded for offensiveness. Categorisation of offensiveness can only be done on the most general of bases: mildly, generally, and particularly. But even then, different groups will be offended to a greater or lesser extent by any given phrase. Context will also play an important part in offensiveness. This question therefore appears to be a matter of opinion.

Comment: Easy answer: avoid.

Comment: It is only in recent years that the censors of American broadcast networks have tolerated allowing that synonym for *butt* to be uttered on the air. It is still considered coarse slang by many, and it will offend some who are prone to such sensitivities. But even telling someone to stick something up their butt is an unquestionably rude demand. The artful orator will express the same sentiment via more elaborate circumlocutions and indirect allusions less likely to cause instantaneous insult merely from the choice of the words uttered rather than from the ultimate intent, which is unchanged.

Comment: To spell it out: A man suggesting to another man to stick it is suggesting either to be raped, or to happily bottom when in fact both men are of course not there to please other men. Only worthless men are. Shortened to: *Go get raped, but you'd like that*.

Comment: The issue in the regulation is not the offensiveness of any particular phrase, but the offensiveness of particular words, regardless of context.  "Ass" in US English is inappropriate in cultured and formal contexts, but common in other environments, depending on personal taste, e.g., among high-school and older athletes.  (E.g., ""We got our asses kicked in this game" is something not unusual to hear.)  The phrase you asked about is highly offensive and a strong insult, but doesn't use words that are in themselves considered universally offensive and so are not prohibited under the regulation.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and explanations. The distinction made between the offensiveness of individual words and what the phrase ultimately intents to convey was helpful to me. I realize that having learned English in narrow contexts personally I am prone to tying in literal meanings with allusions too restrictively.